# xcode 6.0.1 crash after running(On Device) an "old app" on build on Xcode 5

Tags: iphone, crash, device, xcode6

xcode 6.0.1 crash after running(On Device) an "old app" on  build on Xcode 5 
i update my Xcode, and mac and i can't run any app on my Device(5s);

the Xcode :

```
  Process:         Xcode [7643]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode`enter code here`
Version:         6.0.1 (6528)
Build Info:      IDEFrameworks-6528000000000000~2
App Item ID:     497799835
App External ID: 712682811
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [271]
Responsible:     Xcode [7643]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-09-26 11:40:23.257 +0300
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.5 (13F34)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  3981ABEB-E470-A24E-A604-A11BF9E881B4

Sleep/Wake UUID: 6092F049-E546-49B8-A9C5-DBC89D84F552

Crashed Thread:  28  Dispatch queue: Device Install Queue

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6A317
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-6528/DVTFoundation/FilePaths/DVTFilePath.m:802
Details:  fsrep is relative ('גÄ‮-‬‭/‬גÄ‮,‬var/folders/pj/8g6bc_cn6pn01ycfttp_55kr0000gn/CגÄ‮-‬‭/‬גÄ‮,‬‭/‬com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.0.1‭/‬Xcode') parentPath must not be nil but it is.
Object:   <DVTFilePath>
Method:   +_filePathForParent:fileSystemRepresentation:length:allowCreation:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fe986d2f210>{name = (null), num = 16}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set English as primary language and remove any other language (System preferences>Language and Region), then restart.

Comment: Didn't work for me. English was already my only language. Tried installing another then removing and restarting.